# Using training weights on a non-training data to design a new loss function

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I would like to access the training point(s) at a training iteration and incorporate a soft constraint into my loss function by using data points not included in the training set. I will use [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51746005/how-to-restrict-the-sum-of-predicted-outputs-in-a-neural-network-regression-usin) as a reference.

```
import numpy as np
import keras.backend as K
from keras.layers import Dense, Input
from keras.models import Model

# Some random training data and labels
features = np.random.rand(100, 5)
labels = np.random.rand(100, 2)

# Simple neural net with three outputs
input_layer = Input((20,))
hidden_layer = Dense(16)(input_layer)
output_layer = Dense(3)(hidden_layer)


# Model
model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)


#each training point has another data pair. In the real example, I will have multiple 
#supporters. That is why I am using dict.

holder =  np.random.rand(100, 5)
iter = np.arange(start=1, stop=features.shape[0], step=1)
supporters = {}

for i,j in zip(iter, holder): #i represent the ith training data
    supporters[i]=j


# Write a custom loss function
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    # Normal MSE loss
    mse = K.mean(K.square(y_true-y_pred), axis=-1)
    new_constraint = .... 

       

    return(mse+new_constraint)


model.compile(loss=custom_loss, optimizer='sgd')
model.fit(features, labels, epochs=1, ,batch_size=1=1)
```

For simplicity, let us assume that I'd like to minimize the minimum absolute value difference between the prediction value and the prediction of the pair data stored in `supporters` by using the fixed network weights. Also, assume that I pass one training point at each batch. However, I could not figure out how to perform this opeartion. I've tried something shown below, but clearly, it is not correct.

`new_constraint = K.sum(y_pred -  model.fit(supporters))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fit is the procedure of training evaluating the model. I think that it would be better for your problem to load a new instance of your model with your current weights and evaluate the batch loss in order to calculate the loss of  the main model.

```
main_model = Model()  # This is your main training model 

def custom_loss_1(y_true, y_pred):  # Avoid recursive calls
    mse = K.mean(K.square(y_true-y_pred), axis=-1)
    return mse

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    support_model =  tf.keras.models.clone_model(main_model)  # You copy the main model but the weights are uninitialized
    support_model.build((20,)) # You build with inputs same as your support data
    support_model.compile(loss=custom_loss_1, optimizer='sgd') 
    support_model.set_weights(main_model.get_weights())  # You  load the weight of the main model

    mse = custom_loss_1(y_true, y_pred)
    # You just want to evaluate the model, not to train. If you have more
    # metrics than just loss the use support_model.evaluate(supporters)[0]
    new_constraint = K.sum(y_pred -  support_model.predict(supporters))  # predict to get the output, evaluate to get the metrics

    return(mse+new_constraint)
```

Comment: Thanks for the great MWE. Why can't I use the ````evaluate```` method provided by the main model directly? or can't I do a quick evaluation by using the weights of the original model? The reason for asking is that cloning the model and all these copying operations might cause time and space issues. Don't you think?

Comment: Yeah, for sure it would be computational demanding task. I think another solution would be to instantiate the same model two times and set `second_model.trainable=False`. Then set the weights to be the same as the first model after each batch and then use both outputs of the trainable and non-trainable models in your loss function or concatenate the final outputs,( probably in logits form) and process them seperatetly in your loss function.

Comment: One last question, how does the tensor flow figure out which supporter vector corresponds to which training point?

Comment: You should provide them as a single sample and then process the input