# how to imply a different loss function for each batch

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

After getting responded to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69036787/using-training-weights-on-a-non-training-data-to-design-a-new-loss-function), I realized that I have a different question.

I would like to have a different objective component based on the batch that I am passing during a training step. Suppose my batch size is one and I associate each training data with two supporter vectors that are not part of the training step. So I need to figure out which part of the input vector is currently being processed.

```
import numpy as np
import keras.backend as K
from keras.layers import Dense, Input
from keras.models import Model

features = np.random.rand(100, 5)
labels = np.random.rand(100, 2)

holder =  np.random.rand(200, 5) # each feature gets two supporter. 
iter = np.arange(start=1, stop=features.shape[0], step=1)
supporters = {}

for i,j in zip(iter, holder): #(i, i+1) represent the ith training data
    supporters[i]=j
```

For instance, the first two rows of `supporters` is for the first point in `feature`.

```
features[0]  [0.71444629 0.77256729 0.95375736 0.18759234 0.8207317 ]
```

has the following two supporters.

```
1: array([0.76281692, 0.18698215, 0.11687052, 0.78084761, 0.10293403]), 
2: array([0.98229912, 0.08784577, 0.08109571, 0.23665783, 0.52587238])
```

Now, I create a simple model.

```
# Simple neural net with three outputs
input_layer = Input((5,))
hidden_layer = Dense(16)(input_layer)
output_layer = Dense(2)(hidden_layer)


# Model
model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
```

My goal is to create a loss function as

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    # Normal MSE loss
    mse = K.mean(K.square(y_true-y_pred), axis=-1)
    #Assume that I properly pass model object into the method use the predict method
    #to use the current network weights
    new_constraint = K.sum(y_pred -  model.predict(supporters)) 
    return(mse+new_constraint)
```

Then, I go ahead and compile my model.

```
model.compile(loss=custom_loss, optimizer='sgd')
model.fit(features, labels, epochs=1, ,batch_size=1)
```

The problem is that since the batch size is one, I want to make sure that the loss function only considers the supporter of the current training input. For example, if I am training the third point in `features`, then I want to use the fifth and sixth vectors while creating `new_constraint`. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it like this (I have used the TensorFlow based Keras api but it shouldn't matter)

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Input, layers, Model
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

features = np.random.rand(100, 5)
labels = np.random.rand(100, 2)

supporters =  np.random.rand(200, 5) # each feature gets two supporter. 


# I will get both support vectors to iterate over
supporters_1 = supporters[::2, :]
supporters_2 = supporters[1::2, :]

print(supporters_1.shape, supporters_2.shape)
# Result -> ((100, 5), (100, 5))

# Create a tf dataset to use in training
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(((features, supporters_1, supporters_2), labels)).batch(1)

# A look at what it returns
for i in dataset:
    print(i)
    break

'''
Result:
((<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 5), dtype=float64, numpy=array([[0.42834492, 0.01041871, 0.53058175, 0.69453215, 0.83901092]])>, 
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 5), dtype=float64, numpy=array([[0.1724601 , 0.14386688, 0.49018201, 0.13565471, 0.35159235]])>, 
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 5), dtype=float64, numpy=array([[0.87243349, 0.98779049, 0.98405784, 0.74069913, 0.25763667]])>), 
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 2), dtype=float64, numpy=array([[0.20993531, 0.70153453]])>)
'''

#=========================================================
# Creating the model (Input size is 5 and not 2 in your sample so I changed it)
# Same for the label shape
input_layer = Input((5,))
hidden_layer = layers.Dense(16)(input_layer)
output_layer = layers.Dense(2)(hidden_layer)

# Model
model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
#=========================================================


# Implementing the custom loss
# Without the `K.abs` the result can be negative and hence the `K.abs`
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred, support_pred_1, support_pred_2):
    mse = tf.keras.losses.mse(y_true, y_pred)
    new_constraint = K.abs(K.sum(y_pred -  [support_pred_1, support_pred_2]))
    return (mse+new_constraint)

# Instantiate an optimizer.
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-3)


'''
Now we create a custom training loop. In this we will get the logits
of all the inputs and then compute loss using the custom loss
function and then optimize on that loss.
'''
epochs = 10
for epoch in range(epochs):
    print("Start of epoch %d" % (epoch,))
    for step, ((features, support_1, support_2), labels) in enumerate(dataset):

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            logits = model(features, training=True)
            logits_1 = model(support_1, training=True)
            logits_2 = model(support_2, training=True)
            
            loss_value = custom_loss(labels, logits, logits_1, logits_2)

        grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))

    print('loss_value: ', loss_value)
```

EDIT: There is another way to do this. As below:

```
# Everthing same till the supporters_1, supporters_2

def combine(inputs, targets):
    features = inputs[0]
    supports1 = inputs[1]
    supports2 = inputs[2]
    # Stack the inputs as a batch
    final = tf.stack((features, support_1, support_2))
    final = tf.reshape(final, (3,5))
    return final, targets


# Creating the dataset
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(((features, supporters_1, supporters_2), labels)).batch(1)
dataset = dataset.map(combine, num_parallel_calls=-1)

# Check the output
for i in dataset:
    print(i)
    break
'''
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 5), dtype=float64, numpy=
array([[0.35641985, 0.93025517, 0.72874829, 0.81810538, 0.46682277],
       [0.95497516, 0.71722253, 0.10608685, 0.37267656, 0.94748968],
       [0.04822454, 0.00480376, 0.08479184, 0.51133809, 0.38242403]])>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 2), dtype=float64, numpy=array([[0.21399956, 0.97149716]])>)
'''

#================MODEL=================
input_layer = Input((5,))
hidden_layer = layers.Dense(16)(input_layer)
output_layer = layers.Dense(2)(hidden_layer)

# Model
model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
#=======================================

# change the loss function accordingly
'''
The first row in the y_pred will be the prediction corresponding to
actual features and the rest will be predictions corresponding to
supports and hence you can change the loss function as below.
'''
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    mse = tf.keras.losses.mse(y_true, y_pred[0, :])
    new_constraint = K.abs(K.sum(y_pred[0, :] -  y_pred[1:, :]))
    return (mse+new_constraint)


# Compile
model.compile(loss=custom_loss, optimizer='adam')
# train
model.fit(dataset, epochs=5)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you elaborate on what your code is doing? For instance, what is ````combine````, because I am receiving an error there. 
Looking at it, ```dataset``` has only one row from the training set. If I don't specify ```batch``` while defining ```dataset```, and instead use ````model.fit(dataset, epochs=5, batch_size=1)````, would that work? Also, how do we guarantee that supporters are not used during the training step as input? I'm asking this because ````dataset```` includes the supporter vectors and we send them into the ````fit```` method.

Comment: My goal is to use supporters only in the loss function not during the training meaning that they should not be used as input vectors.

Comment: @ball_jan What combine does is that it takes in a feature and the 2 support vectors and returns a tensor. The first dimension of the returned tensor can be considered at the `n_samples` and the second dimension as the `target`. Now, when we are training the model. The model only considers the `inputs` So basically it will generate a `y_pred` for all `the features, and the 2 support vectors`. Now it's up to us how we want to calculate the loss.

Comment: @ball_jan As you said the loss should be calculated in the following manner. For the first `prediction which comes from features, the loss will be computed against the `targets` but for the next 2 predictions which come from the `supports` the loss will be calculated against the `prediction which came from features`.

Comment: So I would like the model to generate ````y_pred```` only for ````features````. The support vectors will be only used during the loss function. That is why I need to figure out which input vector is being processed during the SGD operation. So the loss function is created based on the support vectors related to the corresponding input vector. Sorry if my question was not clear.

Comment: Overall, my goal is to have a different loss function based on the training points used at each batch. I can pass the entire input vector inside the loss function but I don't know how I am going to identify which training point inside the vector input is being processed.