# How do I use a mask based mse loss for images in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning

I want to develop a custom MSE (mean squared error) loss function based on mask region. I have images and corresponding masks. So what I want my loss function to do is to just calculate the mean squared error (MSE) loss over mask pixels and train that way. The issue I face is how to supply a mask to the loss function that is to be used while training as TensorFlow only allows two arguments (y_true,y_pred) for the custom loss function.

I have searched for this everywhere and tried lots of workarounds but found no luck. I would be utterly grateful if you can help me here.

For better representation, showing it what I've already tried:

```
def outer(mask):
    def mask_mse_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        #SomeCode
        return mse_loss
    return mask_mse_loss

model.compile(loss=outer(mask_y_train), optimizer='adam')
```

mask_y_train is list of masks corresponding to y_train which I use for training. The issue is, when I supply mask_y_train to outer(mask) function, it takes it as it is of shape (150,504,504) but X_train, y_train are taken batchwise while training with batch size of 16. So getting this error:
Incompatible shapes: [16,504,504] vs. [150,504,504]

Answer (score 0):

For defining a custom loss function you should define a new class with a "call" method which is called when using a loss function for training. you could add as many as needed arguments to it and use them to calculate the loss value.

this [link](https://medium.com/@Bloomore/how-to-write-a-custom-loss-function-with-additional-arguments-in-keras-5f193929f7a0) could help you.

Please if you get your answer, mark it as "Answered".

Comment: `code
def outer(mask):
    def mask_mse_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        #SomeCode
        return mse_loss
    return mask_mse_loss
`
model.compile(loss=outer(mask_y_train), optimizer='adam')
Here the issue is mask_y_train consists of corresponding masks for y_train that I give to the model, so it has shape say (150,504,504) but my model takes input batchwise in batches of 16 (batch_size). So, there comes shape mismatch error: Incompatible shapes: [16,504,504] vs. [150,504,504]. Have I explained it properly?

Comment: Updated in better formatting in question itself. Please refer that if previous comment seems confusing.

Comment: Oh, you mean for every image you have a corresponding mask, in this case, I suggest you apply the masks on images for all data and then feed it to the network as input. In fact, it could be a preprocessing step.

Comment: Okay will look into it. Actually I didn't want to go in that direction, the purpose of my project is to develop a custom loss function. Can you suggest some other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

dear friend I become too curios about this problem, so I search for a proper solution :)

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69050266/how-to-imply-a-different-loss-function-for-each-batch) maybe is what you're looking for. You could change the input tensor in the way it contains the input and the corresponding masks, then in your custom loss function manage to calculate loss properly.